# When the user selects text (whether by mouse or keyboard), it is possible to receive it? (c#)

Tags: c#, windows, mouseevent, selection, low-level

In my app I want to get the text that was selected whenever the user selects a text, system-widely, maybe using a Low Level Mouse Hook.
Is this possible?

Comment: Only in your application or system-wide? What about keyboard selection?

Comment: Are you asking about Windows, or cross platform with portable C# stuff? (in case there's a difference)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll edit the question.
Yes, I need a it system-wide, and I also want the keyborad selection.

Comment: @PeterCordes windows only

Comment: This is best done using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/), or [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/winevents-infrastructure).